# Drawing different circles with intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I found the following in this forum:

```
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}   
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}   
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.1cm) circle (1.5cm)}
```

My goal is to draw three circles with intersections. It works fine. But i do not know why. It's clear what the coordinate (0,0) in the definition of the first circle means.

But how can I interprete (60:2.1cm) or (0:2.1cm)?

Comment: I think those are polar coordinates. So `(60:2.1cm)` is at an angle of `60` degrees and a radius of `2.1cm`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. Now it is clear.